# IF condition in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables: `students`, `ece200_atten`.

- First table `students` has 2 columns: `id, ece200`, but `ece200` is `bit` => true or false
- Second table `ece200_attend` has a column `id`

When I insert `id` I want to check (if ece200 of this id = 1 ) insert that id in table ece200_attend  .

My code:

```
alter proc test
   @myid int    
as 
begin
   declare @mycourse bit = 1

   select @mycourse = ece200 from students 

   if @mycourse = 1
      insert into ece200_attend (id) values (@myid)
end
go

exec test 34003
```

Comment: so what problem in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if exists (select * from students where id = @myid and ece2000 = 1)
    begin
    insert into ece200_attend (id) values (@myid)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
ALTER PROC test(@myid int)
AS BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM STUDENTS WHERE ece200=1)
    INSERT INTO ece200_attend (id) values (@myid)
GO


EXEC TEST 34003
```